# Stop SCP from password prompt

Tags: bash, key, scp

I am trying to copy my profile to a list of servers ( 5K ). I am using a private key to get the authentication working. Everything runs smoothly and as expected but I have this small annoyance :

Sometimes a server does not accept my key ( thats ok, I dont care if a few servers dont receive my profile ) but as the same was rejected, a prompt pops up asking for password and stops the execution until I type CTRL-C to abort it.

How can I make sure SCP uses the key and ONLY the key, and never prompts for any password?

NOTE : Im planning to add an ampersand at the end so all the copies will be done in parallel later.

#### Code

```
#!/bin/bash

while read server
do
    scp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ./.bash_profile rouser@${server}:/home/rouser/
    
done <<< "$( cat all_servers.txt )"
```

Comment: Did you consider reading [`scp`'s manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html)?  It pretty clearly documents a `-B` ("batch") option that seems designed precisely for your purpose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks. Actually I did, and I totally did not see that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-B' Selects batch mode (prevents asking for passwords or passphrases)